# Error con select2 en angular 5

Tags: angular, select2

estoy tratando de darle estas funciones a una pantalla que he creado [select 2 ejemplos ng2-select2](https://nejczdovc.github.io/ng2-select2-demo/)  (es el primer select , el mas basico)

el problema es que al parecer no esta soportado para angular 5, solo para angular 2

Mi error es el siguiente :

```
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'select2'.
```

Estoy haciendo un ejemplo muy basico siguiendo esta pagina [select2 basic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-select2), como pueden ver son solo unas cuantas lineas y no hay errores de codigo o de importaciones etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yo estaba teniendo el mismo error (usando Angular 7). Hasta que incluí manualmente en el archivo app.module.ts

```
import { Select2Module } from 'ng2-select2';
```

Y agregué a los imports el `Select2Module` y `FormsModule`:

```
imports: [
  ...
  FormsModule,
  Select2Module
```

Eso funcionó para mi, también tener en cuenta los pre-requisitos, que son tener agregado jquery y select2 en el proyecto, en mi caso los agregué con `yarn add jquery` y luego `yarn add select2`, y por último incluir la ruta en los scripts del archivo angular.json

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar ng-select debes agregar en el module:

```
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';

imports: [    
......,
NgSelectModule
]
```

y en el HTML va:

```
    <ng-select placeholder="Texto aqui" name="stock" [(ngModel)]="valorenobjeto" [virtualScroll]="true"
                [compareWith]="compare" notFoundText="texto no encontrado" 
                [loading]="loadingBoolean" loadingText="Cargando...">
                <ng-option *ngFor="let registro of registros" [value]="registro">
                  {{ registro.valor }} 
                </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Podes encontrar mas informacion en el siguiente link:

[ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select)